# number_format without rounding

Tags: php

Is there a `number_format` alternative in PHP that allows me to chose thousands and decimal separator, while keeping the number of decimals? E.g. something like this:

```
number_format_alternative( '1234.617', ',', '.' );

>1 234,617
```

but

```
number_format_alternative( '120.0', ',', '.' );
>120.0
```

I realize that I could achieve almost the same thing, by using a ridiculously high number of decimals, and trimming all zeros from  the right, though the second example would then look like:

```
number_format_alternative( 120.0, ',', '.' );
>120
```

**edit:** This is what I ended up doing:

```
function numberOfDecimals( $number ) {
   return strlen(strstr(rtrim(sprintf('%.10F', $number), '0'), '.'))-1;
}
```

Comment: Not that I'd know, you'd have to implement your own version of that. The reason why we have that `$decimals` parameter is the imprecision of floats. (by the way: your string is first casted to a float in number_format, that's why any information about trailing zeroes is lost)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inputting the number to the function as a string you could use a regular expression to see how many digits are after the decimal point, represented by '.' in this case, and then execute `number_format` with the `$decimals` parameter set to the number you just calculated.

One regular expression that would work would be `\.\d+` and then minus 1 off the length to find the decimals number, you could use a look behind how ever I think the performance would be worse. Some testing may be needed and I am sure there will be other regular expressions that would work.

Comment: in that approach I wouldn't even need a regexp, I could just `strlen(strstr($val, '.'))-1`

Comment: @leo Using `strlen(strstr($val, '.'))-1` to set the `$decimals` parameter would work in the same way and may run slightly faster than regular expression functions, although I have never tested the speed of `strstr` in PHP.