# number_format rounding up number that end with 5 decimal

Tags: php, number-formatting

Is there a way to make number_format not to round up numbers that end up with a "5" decimal?

```
echo number_format(25.58,1); // 25.6 - OK 
echo number_format(85.72,1); // 85.7 - OK 
echo number_format(26.25,1); // 26.3 - WHY? 26.2 needed here.
```

Note: I'm not asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017233/number-format-without-rounding)

Comment: 26.5 doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you don't mean 26.2?

Comment: Because you have specified 1 decimal place. Converting `25` to one decimal place will result in 3

Comment: @rjdown Sure, just corrected my question.

Comment: @Vector yes, and I need a way to make number_format ignore this rounding when the last decimal is a 5.

Comment: So .6 is ok to round up, .5 should round down?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `number_format()` use the [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function. You can specify how you want it to round.

```
echo round(25.58, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 25.6
echo round(85.72, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 85.7
echo round(26.25, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 26.2
```

Comment: Note: PHP 5.3+ only (plenty of 5.2 or older servers running still, unfortunately)

Comment: This is the method I would choose (subject to php version obviously)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear on what you are trying to achieve. Based on your comment of 'ignoring' numbers that end in five i have mocked up a very basic quick function that does this

```
echo format_numbers(25.58,1); // 25.6 
echo format_numbers(85.72,1); // 85.7 
echo format_numbers(26.25,1); // 26.2 

function format_numbers($number, $decimal)
{
    if(substr($number, -1) == '5'){
        $number = $number - 0.1;
    }
    return number_format($number, $decimal);

}
```

This example is for PHP versions that do not support the prefered method of `round(26.25, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)`. The above example will deduct `0.1` from the number thus forcing `number_format()` to round down.